# Rails polymorphic relationship without specifying source type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

In my app, I've got an ItemList which can contain either Photos or Videos so I'm using a polymporphic relationship to signify the associations. (Bear in mind there are many other classes than just `Photo` and `Video`

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_items
  has_many :photos, through: :list_items, source: :listable, source_type: 'Photo'
  has_many :videos, through: :list_items, source: :listable, source_type: 'Video'
end

class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This works OK in that I can do stuff like...

```
my_photo = Photo.last
some_list.photos << my_photo
some_list.photos #=> [my_photo]
some_list.videos #=> []
```

But is there a way I can do the following:

```
my_photo = Photo.last
some_list.list_items << my_photo
```

Because at the moment I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ListItem(#70318368851760) expected, got Photo(#70318311121120)
```

The reason I want to do it is to avoid this situation:

```
obj = get_some_object
if obj.is_a?(Photo)
  my_list.photos << obj
elsif obj.is_a?(Video)
  my_list.videos << obj
elsif
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Could you explain why you would want to do `some_list.list_items << my_photo` instead of `some_list.photos << my_photo` ?

Comment: I've edited my question to explain why I want to do this.

Comment: Can you please expand the classes code to show inheritance.  I'm assuming that Photo and Video inherit from ListItem, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

a quick solution could be:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :list_items do
   def << (item)
    i = ListItem.create(listable: item)
    super i
   end
 end
 has_many :photos, through: :list_items, source: :listable, source_type: 'Photo'
 has_many :videos, through: :list_items, source: :listable, source_type: 'Video'
end
```